# PHP Form - Update database row using one or more checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

Currently stuck trying to configure a php page to update a MySQL database row "orderStatus" by checking one or more checkboxes. It should update the orderStatus of the selected row(s) to "validated" once the form is submitted. It's updating only the first row of the table likely due to **$orderID = $_POST['id'];** in the validate.php snippet. What I tried to do is retrieve all the orderIDs of the rows that have been checked and assign it to the variable/array $orderID, so that the orderStatus is changed only for those rows.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<header>
<title>Validate an Order</title>

</header>
<body>

<h1>Validate an Order</h1>
<h4>Showing all unvalidated orders.</h4>
<br/>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orderStatus = 'processing' ORDER BY orderDate DESC");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Validate?</th>
<th>OrderID</th>
<th>OrderDate</th>
<th>OrderShipDate</th>
<th>OrderType</th>
<th>OrderMedia</th>
<th>OrderContent</th>
<th>OrderStatus</th>
<th>OrderQuantity</th>
<th>OrderCost</th>
<th>OrderDeposit</th>
<th>OrderDesc</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<form action='validate.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['orderID']."'><input type='checkbox' name='validate[]' value='validated'>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderDate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderShipDate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderType'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderMedia'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderContent'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderStatus'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderQuantity'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderCost'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderDeposit'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderDesc'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP for the form:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$orderID = $_POST['id'];

    if(isset($_POST['validate'])){
    foreach($_POST['validate'] as $validate){
       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE orders SET orderStatus = '$validate' WHERE orderID = $orderID");
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Here's what the page looks like.

[Validate an Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1MQG.jpg)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please print_r($_POST['validate']) is it echo all values?

Comment: You are creating a `<form>` for each `$row` loop. And since you are only sending 1 `validate` value in a form, that is why only the 1st one is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Form is inside while loop.When you're using  with  you need to either put the  tags completely outside the , or have the entire  inside one . Any other structure breaks the syntax of the  and will be ignored by the browser, or rendered incorrectly.

Please try this

```
<html>
<header>
<title>Validate an Order</title>

</header>
<body>

<h1>Validate an Order</h1>
<h4>Showing all unvalidated orders.</h4>
<br/>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orderStatus = 'processing' ORDER BY orderDate DESC");
echo "<form action='validate.php' method='post'>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Validate?</th>
<th>OrderID</th>
<th>OrderDate</th>
<th>OrderShipDate</th>
<th>OrderType</th>
<th>OrderMedia</th>
<th>OrderContent</th>
<th>OrderStatus</th>
<th>OrderQuantity</th>
<th>OrderCost</th>
<th>OrderDeposit</th>
<th>OrderDesc</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['orderID']."'><input type='checkbox' name='validate[]' value='validated'>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderDate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderShipDate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderType'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderMedia'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderContent'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderStatus'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderQuantity'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderCost'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderDeposit'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderDesc'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>"
. "</form>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did not check weather this code going to work or not, but i am assuming your form is going to work, but than you still have to correct his validate.php, Hint -- just add the index in the `$orderId`, so when ever the loop return it increases. i think than its going to be fine

Comment: @arif_suhail_123-Sorry arif i didn't get you...can you please edit my code?

Comment: no i dont want to touch, as i dont know what else is wrong, all i am saying is this $orderId is not single value, it's an array, if you see the picture, so when you run the query you need to take care of it. his query is like this `mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE orders SET orderStatus = '$validate' WHERE orderID = $orderID");` in here orderID, is single value he should some thing like this declare the variable `$i` before the loop and than run this query. `mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE orders SET orderStatus = '$validate' WHERE orderID = '".$orderID[$i++]."'"); so the each time pointer moves
`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! I wound up changing the input checkbox tag in the HTML to: `<input type="checkbox" name="vid[]" id="validate" value='.$row['orderID'].'` This grabs the orderIDs of those rows selected into the vid[] array.

Then in validate.php, the query sets the status to "validate" using $vid from foreach():

```
// if the vid array exists
if(isset($_POST['vid'])) {

// Loop through vid array "containing orderIDs" and set orderStatus to "validated" only for those orderIDs
foreach($_POST['vid'] as $vid) {
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE orders SET orderStatus = 'validated' WHERE orderID = '$vid'");
}
}
```